# how can i make my discord bot do the !say command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, chatbot, replit

I've never coded before so I'm pretty new and I'm trying python on replit, I've searched a lot and this is what I did so far but it isn't working. (ignore the reverse part)

```
import os        
import discord      
from keep_alive import keep_alive 

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event  
async def on_ready():  
    print("I'm in")  
    print(client.user)   

@client.event  
async def on_message(message):  
    if message.content.startswith("!reverse"):  
        await message.channel.send(message.content[::-1])   

my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']  
client.run(my_secret)

keep_alive()  
my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']  
client.run(my_secret)   

async def on_message(message):  
    echo = message.content.split(" ", 1)[1]  
    if message.content.startswith("!say"):  
     await message.channel.send(echo)
```

I want the bot to be like this:
me:!say blah blah blah
bot: blah blah blah

thanks to anyone that answers

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of problems here

- `Intents.default()` doesn't include the `message contents` intent, so you won't be able to read messages. For more info on intents and how to enable them, read the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html
- You've got two `on_message` functions, which doesn't work. You can't have multiple functions with the same name. Combine them into one instead.
- Never put any code underneath `client.run()` - it'll never get executed.
- You've got two `client.run()`'s. Why?
- The `on_message` at the bottom is missing the `@client.event` decorator, so even if you wouldn't have 2 of them it still wouldn't be invoked.
- Why don't you use a `Bot` with `command`s instead of manually parsing everything in `on_message`? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html
- Replit isn't made to run bots on and will cause you a lot of trouble. Consider hosting it on an actual VPS (or during the development phase - just locally).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's some other changes to make first.

You're not using commands, and are instead looking for messages(technically nothing wrong with that, but it can cause unnecessary issues)

I'll modify the code, and hopefully, it works.

```py
import os        
import discord      
from keep_alive import keep_alive 

client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event  
async def on_ready():  
    print("I'm in")  
    print(client.user)   

  
@client.command()
async def reverse(ctx,*,message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.channel.send(message[::-1])

my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']  
client.run(my_secret)

keep_alive()  
my_secret = os.environ['DISCORD_BOT_SECRET']  
client.run(my_secret)  
 
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.channel.send(message)
```